# Fetch Facebook logged-in user's Interest using Facebook iOS SDK API v2.4

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook SDK API v2.4 and trying to fetch user's interest.

From version change log in Facebook, I saw that "user_interests" permission as well "/v2.3/{user_id}/interests" is deprecated.

I didn't saw any exact replacement for the same.

In my app, I was using "user_interest" permission earlier but as I am using new Facebook SDK now, I am unable to use it.

Also I have been suggested to use get user likes but I saw that is something different.

Is there any way to get user interests using new Facebook api version?

Comment: Sorry. I am using latest sdk. I meant to say api version. Corrected now.

Comment: As per Facebook new api 2.0, your app should not ask for users friends_interests. Check the module 'Login -> Permission changes' from link  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading

Comment: don''t use facebook api 2.4 now use facebook api 2.5...facebook update api 2.5

Answer (score 0):

Yes I do agree. But, what I am trying to get is user interests from this section(see below):

[image]

And as per the change log document [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3) this process is deprecated.

See below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It was just a group of of user liked pages and you can just get the user/likes instead: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/likes